# How to dynamically load a javascript file from a server with Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, basic-authentication

We have a website that is protected by Basic Authentication and has a particular javascript file underneath it.

I want to load that javascript file from a different MVC3 site by putting details on the authentication header when loading the file and here's what I'm trying that doesn't seem to work - it's always popping up the basic authentication login dialog:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Auth test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Base64.js"></script>
    <h2>Index</h2>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {

            var auth = make_base_auth('domain\user', 'password');

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': auth
                }
            });


            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost/WebClient/scripts/bob.js',
                dataType: 'script',
                //username: 'domain\user',
                //password: 'password',
                //withCredentials: true,
                //crossDomain: true,
                //headers: { 'Authorization': auth },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Got the script!");

                    callFunctionInTheOtherJSFile();
                },
                async: false
            });


        });

        function make_base_auth(user, password) {
            var tok = user + ':' + password;
            var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
            return "Basic " + hash;
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what I should do to get the the code to work?

As you'll see from the various commented out parts - I've tried a few different ways (newer and older jQuery methods etc)!

For reference, the Base64 JS is taken from here - http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html as described here - http://coderseye.com/2007/how-to-do-http-basic-auth-in-ajax.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the standard `http://user:pass@hostname/` syntax ?

Comment: Yes - that didn't work either.  Although that maybe because I need to add the user's domain in as well - i.e. http://domain\user:pass@hostname/

Comment: Note that the url is also under https if that makes any difference